# Pass a function to evaluate() in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, xpath, puppeteer

I'm working on a web scraper in Typescript using Puppeteer and made a helper function like this:

```
function evaluateXPath(page: puppeteer.Page, xpath: string): Promise<any[]> {
    return page.waitForXPath(xpath)
        .then(() => page.$x(xpath))
        .then(handles => page.evaluate((...handles) => handles.map(h => h.href), ...handles))
}
```

It works fine if I want to get the value of the href-field of an xpath, but I want to make it more generic. Something like this (replaced 'h => h.href' inside map() with 'evalFunc'):

```
function evaluateXPath(page: puppeteer.Page, xpath: string, evalFunc: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => any): Promise<any[]> {
    return page.waitForXPath(xpath)
        .then(() => page.$x(xpath))
        .then(handles => page.evaluate((...handles) => handles.map(evalFunc), ...handles))
}
```

This obviously doesn't work since 'evalFunc' doesn't exist in browser context, but any attempts at passing the function to the browser fails or doesn't compile. Passing it inside the evaluate() function doesn't work since it's not assignable to a parameter of type 'SerializableOrJSHandle' and I've had no luck with the exposeFunction() function either.

Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: What kind of action do you perform with the `handles`?

Comment: If you don't mind writing it out in the page.evaluate, you can just put `window.nameMe = function() {}` in the evaluate function. Unless I misunderstood your question...

Comment: I want to be able to pass an arbitrary function (withing limits ofc, such as getting the href/innerText and occasionally make a simple if-case) to be evaluated in browser-context. Having to define every function I intend to use inside the helper function would be inconvenient and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two dubious and inconvenient solutions.

1. Using `eval()` or `Function()` constructor inside the evaluated function and transfer the function code as a string (difficult for code writing, linting etc. — this can be mitigated a bit by using `Function.prototype.toString()`).
2. Placing all the utility functions in a file and using [`page.addScriptTag()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions) to inject this file so that the evaluated function can call any of the functions declared in this file (this can pollute the global scope).

Edit:

```
function evaluateXPath(page: puppeteer.Page, xpath: string, evalFunc: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => any): Promise<any[]> {
    return page.waitForXPath(xpath)
        .then(() => page.$x(xpath))
        .then(handles => page.evaluate((evalFuncStr, ...handles) =>
            handles.map(eval(`(${evalFuncStr})`)),
            evalFunc.toString(),
            ...handles))
}
```

Comment: Just a late thought. `eval(evalFuncStr)` will declare a function. If you use anonymous functions or want function expressions, it should be `eval(\`(${evalFuncStr})\`) `

Comment: I haven't used the eval function before, nor have I done any extensive testing. My edit worked for my particular case. I'll try your change when I get the time.

Comment: I tried your change and it works as well (for my case). I don't know it's significance, but I'll go with your proposal. Thanks!